# How to wire 2 lights to one switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

Ontario code now requires 14/3 between the switch and the light. Can someone provide a diagram showing how to wire 2 lights controlled by one switch with power coming into the switch & 14/3 between the switch and the first light?

Comment: Are you sure it *always* requires 14/3? That could be, but more logical is the neutral issue - i.e., if power is panel->light(s)->switch to require 14/3 for that last leg so that you have neutral at the switch for smart switches/etc. But panel->switch->light(s) could be done (technically) with switched-hot/neutral - no need to also have unswitched hot.

Comment: Do the require it for _new_ construction, any _renovation_ construction, or must all buildings be immediately upgraded? Seems that some important details are missing here...

Comment: Is power coming first to the light fixture and then to the switch?  If so, current code in the USA also now requires 14/3 (or 12/3) to the switch to provide a neutral for a potential smart switch.   That configuration is called a "switch leg".  If power first goes to the switch and code still required /3 cable, then jay613 may be right.

Comment: Is the second light connected to first light or to the switch?

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](https://www.strathcona.ca/files/files/residential_wiring_best_practices_-_final_copy_march_27.pdf) guide to the 2018 Canadian electrical code which seems to address this issue.  It states, on page 6, that using a 2 conductor cable for a switch leg is no longer approved, and references several figures for approved switch wiring.  Page 16 shows the approved methods, and makes clear that the intent is to have a neutral in each switch box.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard some places are requiring fan-capable wiring to all ceiling boxes.  IDK if your code states the motivation but maybe that's the motivation.   The third wire allows future installation of a ceiling fan. If that is what your code requires you to install, you don't need a diagram. Just daisy chain the two lights from the switch in the normal way with 2+ground wires.  In the switch, and in the light at the end of the chain you cap off the third wire.  In the middle (first light) connect the third wires together.  That way you can later install a fan at the second box without opening the first box.  You probably don't HAVE to do it this way, you can just cap off the third wire everywhere ... but why not go with the spirit of the code?

Comment: Thanks jay613. That is helpful. I am a visual person and a diagram really helps me.